# Save browser image into Directory

Tags: php, image, browser

How to save the image from browser into Directory by PHP code..

First I pass an image into a php file via:

```
<http://localhost/filename.php?image=image.png>
```

I have code like below in filename.php:

```
$image = $_GET['image'];
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

now the image will be shown in the browser. but how I save it into directory?
I tried this

```
 file_put_contents(DIR_IMAGE.'watermark.png', file_get_contents(the link http://.....=image.png));
```

the files is saving into the directory but the file is corrupted/damage. how can I do workable? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fopen` to open directory and `write` (save) the file. ([`fopen php manual`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php))

```
$f = fopen('/home/www/path/image.jpg', 'w');
fwrite($f, $image);
fclose($f);
```